# How to send any new uploaded or created items in the web application to all users in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an **intranet web application** which should provide its users with a weekly medium-size quizzes about the latest training courses that they took in the company.I developed the quiz machine to be similar to this [one explained on ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-20-applications/lesson-11-building-a-quiz-engine-1). 
Now, I need to make the system sending the quizzes at 7 o'clock on every Monday. Since this is my first project in ASP.NET, I need your explanation and some references to help me in implementing this task.

I already implemented a Mail class that uses MailMessage and SMTP Client. I used this class for Contact Us page. But I don't know I will need to use for this case or not.

I googled about this but I could not be able to find any useful resource for this thing except one resource that tells me about designing one empty page and when the user comes to this page, it should send an email. Then, I need to use some called task scheduling to automate the process of sending emails. But how I develop these things?

Any help?

Comment: Your second-best bet is to write a simple Console applicaiton and create a scheduled task on a machine to run it once a week.  The BEST solution would be non-technical. Simply tell your users to take the new quiz every Friday, and it will be available after 7:00 AM.  The more you automate needless emails the more your users will grow accustomed to them and ignore them.  If you REALLY need to send this out, go back to the first suggestion.

Comment: @Cory said it best, don't use a web page for this. Build a windows service or even a console app and then schedule a task to run it.

Comment: Bad idea. That's like hiring a live-in maid to stand around for 23 hours a day so she can clean that one remaining hour instead of having someone come over when it needs to be done. Use the right tool for the right job and leaving a program running all the time not only creates potential issues of its own, it's just not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not build an ASP.NET site/page that only sends e-mails if you're going to need to do so on a timed schedule.

There are better options:

1. Write a Windows Service or console application in .NET that knows how to connect to your database, collect information needed to send e-mails, and use the SMTP client within the framework to send e-mails. Then use the Windows task scheduler or some other enterprise scheduling software to run the job on your required schedule.
2. Create a job within your DBMS that builds and sends the e-mails using a stored procedure or CLR integration (if available).

Depending on the rules created by the e-mail admins, you may need to send e-mails in batches or from a special account so you don't get flagged as a spammer. If the e-mails are external there may be other hoops to jump through (possibly even legal ones via the [CAN-SPAM Act](http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business)).